# A potentially dangerous Request.Path

Tags: asp.net

Been getting a lot of errors like this lately. I did some research and found that this is because html was detected in the input text. Does this mean that someone is trying to hack my website?

I can stop this from happeneing by turning off page validation, but this hardly seems like a good solution.

Here is some info from one of the errors:

```
HTTP_CONNECTION:keep-alive HTTP_ACCEPT:*/* HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-us HTTP_HOST:www.easymuaythai.com HTTP_REFERER:http://www.google.com/search?q=symbolic+tattoos&hl=en&client=safari&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=u5c1T8L-JfLYiAKRs5ixCg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1024&bih=622 HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3
```

Don't know if it matters, but I have a rule in my IIS to prevent image hotlinking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the string you give here seems like some search on **google images** for two words (symbolic tattoos) and end up to your site. Maybe its false, but the words have do with your site.

**99.9% this call is not attack**.

Now asp.net by default take care for every input that maybe use for script injection, or render anything on page. But after your familure with this and you know what you must do you can disabled it.

**What to do:** You can read anything, but write them on page using HtmlEncode, or UrlEncode if you place them on URL, or Attribute Encode if you place this input on attributes. If you import them on SQL then also take care to make your sql queries with parametres.

### HotLinking

The image hotlinking just check if the reference come from your site and I do not think that have to do with this error. How ever because this is an image search, maybe the one is click on this google image, the google creates a script to show this image above and this some how is throw an error... hmmm maybe have to do...

### Update

I found [the link that you give is here](http://www.google.com/imgres?start=12&hl=en&client=safari&sa=X&biw=1181&bih=580&addh=36&tbm=isch&tbnid=ELqfKzUpNc6OdM:&imgrefurl=http://www.easymuaythai.com/post/2012/01/28/Muay-Thai-Tattoo.aspx&docid=9zvGgxN0HMA_DM&imgurl=http://www.easymuaythai.com/image.axd%253Fpicture%253D2012%25252F1%25252FGanesh.jpg&w=375&h=500&ei=lGQ2T8WzNsqR0AXYi8W1Ag&zoom=1) Here is what your users come and see from the above reference. From google chrome is not make any error.

This link is found on the above reference link.

http://www.google.com/search?q=symbolic+tattoos&hl=en&client=safari&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=u5c1T8L-JfLYiAKRs5ixCg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1024&bih=622 HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I tried that link on Firefox and IE and no error was generated for me too. So you suggest I disable request validation? Is this safe?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper I suggest to disabled if the input not rendered on page, or when you render it use htmlEncode.

Comment: No there is no input, but there has to be a better solution than to disable it completely for the website. It just seems so unsafe.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper If we talk for the same think, I have disable it. Focus to what is unsafe, what they potential harm your site ? did you get data ? Did you use the url to show data ? Did you save data ? What from that is throw this error ? MS just throw this is as potential problem and not let anything continue as precaution. But if you not use any of this, where is the issue ?

Comment: There are parts of my site that use query string, such as search and what not. If I disable it, it can be used to harm there. Is it possible to disable it just for requests coming from google.images?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper Maybe is something else... can you locate what is causing it ? seems that come from ipad or something.

Answer (score 2):

Few days ago, while working on an ASP.NET 4.0 Web project, I got an issue. The issue was, when user enters unencoded HTML content into a comment text box s/he got something like the following error message:
"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client".

This was because .NET detected something in the entered text which looked like an HTML statement. Then I got a link Request Validation, that is a feature put in place to protect your application cross site scripting attack and followed accordingly.

To disable request validation, I added the following to the existing "page" directive in that .aspx file.

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

But still I got the same error.

Later I found, for .NET 4, we need to add requestValidationMode="2.0" to the httpRuntime configuration section of the web.config file like the following:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

But if there is no httpRuntime section in the web.config file, then this goes inside the `<system.web>` section.

If anyone wants to turn off request validation for globally user, the following line in the web.config file within  section:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

([source](http://technochecked.blogspot.com/2012/08/aspnet-40-potentially-dangerous.html))

Comment: A good link because you are the owner? Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.