# how to pass and retrieve Html tags via querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, query-string

**Default.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
$("#add_questions").click(function() {
var question = $("#wmd-output").val();
var option1 = $("#option1").val();
var option2 = $("#option2").val();
var option3 = $("#option3").val();
var option4 = $("#option4").val();
var answer = $("#answer").val();
var paper = $("#txt_subject_id").val();
var dataString = 'question='+ question +'&option1='+option1 +'&option2='+option2 +'&option3='+option3 +'&option4='+option4 +'&answer='+answer+'&paper='+paper;

$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="../images/validate.gif" align="absmiddle">');
//alert(dataString)

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "Default2.aspx",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#display").after(html);
//alert(html)
//document.getElementById('content').value='';
//document.getElementById('content').focus();
$("#flash").hide();
}
});
 return false;
});
});

</script>
```

Let

`dataString="question=p>hello</p>&option1=option1&option2=option2&option3=option3&option4=option4&answer=answer&paper=paper"`

How could I pass this query string to next page using jquery? I didn't get response from the next page, which means the `question=<p>hello</p>` not getting the value.

**Default2.aspx**

```
Dim question As String
question = Request.QueryString("question")
Response.Write(question)
```

I also tried `encodeUri` and `encodeURIcomponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thanks to everyone for their effort.

This is what i did

```
question=encodeURIComponent(question)
var dataString = 'question='+ encodeURIComponent(question) +'&option1='+ option1 +'&option2='+ option2 +'&option3='+ option3 +'&option4='+ option4 +'&answer='+ answer +'&paper='+ paper;
```

I have used `encodeURIComponent` twice and while decoding at the server side

`quest = Server.UrlDecode(question)`

display the correct value.

Thanks again for help !!

Comment: by adding it twice you only hide the html characters to avoid the message 'potentially dangerous ...' and when you render it on page is all ready encoded. How ever the one time can do the job as I have write.

Comment: @Aristos thanks for your help !! But, it giving what i need. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You say that you try the `encodeURIcomponent` but I am afraid that you apply it on the full line. You must apply the `encodeURIcomponent` to each value alone to make it work as:

```
var dataString = 'question='+ encodeURIcomponent(question) +'&option1='+ 
  encodeURIcomponent(option1) +'&option2='+ encodeURIcomponent(option2) +'&option3='+ 
   encodeURIcomponent(option3) +'&option4='+ encodeURIcomponent(option4) +'&answer='+ 
     encodeURIcomponent(answer)+'&paper='+ encodeURIcomponent(paper);
```

Also, do you have check that you read the values from `var question = $("#wmd-output").val();` ? is the `"#wmd-output"` the correct one or you need to add the rendered client id ?

Comment: i have checked it through the `alert`, which i wrote inside button click javascript, and i'm getting question=<p>hello</p>&option1=option1&option2=option2&option3=option3&option4=option4&answer=answer&paper=paper

Comment: @coders good, now use the `encodeURIcomponent` as I have type it and try it again

Comment: getting `A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (output-question="<p>Hello</p>").`

Comment: @coders This is a first alert to be carfoul what you goint to be render - render it using htmlEncode, and disable this warning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717703/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client/10721007#10721007

Comment: @coders also read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240044/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path/9240290#9240290

Comment: thanks for your help, but i have done myself. I have used encodeURIComponent twice. Now, it worked !!

Answer (score -2):

I am afraid you can't pass HTML via querystring. You can use Session instead. You can store HTML in a string variable and store it in Session. On next page, you can retrieve it from Session.

```
Session.Add("myHTML","<p></p>");
```

On next page load

```
String html = Session["myHTML"].ToString();
```

Comment: Yes you can pass them via querystring, you only need to make them url safe by encoding them, see what coders says.